# One column ends up with different collation in view

Tags: mysql, mariadb, collation

I've a bit of a strange issue going on. My database is set to the utf8mb4_unicode_ci collation. So are the (WooCommerce) tables within that database. The columns in the table are also at utf8mb4_unicode_ci.

I've create a view and now get a different collation (as utf8mb4_*general*_ci) for the calculated field **sku_class**. How is this possible? And, more important, how can I resolve it?

The shortened query to create the view is:

```
SET character_set_connection = 'utf8mb4';

CREATE VIEW vw_wc_product_details AS 

SELECT
        pm.sku,
        CASE
            -- manual fixes 
            WHEN pm.sku LIKE 'AB1404/%' THEN 'c'    
            -- default rules
            WHEN pm.sku LIKE 'ABs__-_%' THEN 's'    
            WHEN pm.sku LIKE 'ABt__-_%' THEN 't'
            WHEN pm.sku LIKE 'AB____/%' THEN 'pc'  
            WHEN ( SELECT COUNT(sku) FROM wp_wc_product_meta_lookup WHERE sku LIKE CONCAT(pm.sku, '/_%') ) >= 1 THEN 'p' 
            WHEN pm.sku LIKE 'AB____%' AND LENGTH(pm.sku) = 6 THEN 'c' 
            WHEN pm.sku LIKE 'AX%' AND LENGTH(pm.sku) >= 6 THEN 'm'
            ELSE 'x'
        END as sku_class
    
FROM    wp_wc_product_attributes_lookup AS pa
LEFT    JOIN wp_terms AS t ON pa.term_id = t.term_id
LEFT    JOIN wp_wc_product_meta_lookup AS pm ON pa.product_id = pm.product_id
LEFT    JOIN wp_posts AS p ON pa.product_id = p.ID

COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'
```

The `SET character_set_connection = 'utf8mb4';` and `COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'` lines have been added due to the *illegal mix of collations* error I received and which put me on the path of double checking the collations of everything involved.

Comment: What is the value of collation_connection server system variable? This is the collation used for string literals in your case expression.

Comment: @shadow, thanks for the hint, I'll dive into that and come back on it.

Comment: @shadow, okay, found that quicker than expected in the [INFORMATION_SCHEME].[SYSTEM_VARIABLES]. 

Looks to be a very likely source of my problem. The current COLLATION_CONNECTION values are:
 __
session value = utf8mb4_unicode_ci | 
global value = latin1_swedish_ci | 
default value = latin1_swedish_ci
 __

Will have to figure out if I can change these values myself or that I need to ask my hosting party to help me out.

I probably have to correct COLLATION_DATABASE and COLLATION_SERVER as well.

Comment: It is unlikely they will change the global / default value for you, but it is the session one that matters to you. However, the session value seems to be the one you want (unicode) not the general one.

Comment: I agree, have created the support ticket with them to see what's possible. In the meantime I've added COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci' right after the END of each CASE statement. That seems to do the trick. That said, a secondary view that also uses the first view won't open in phpMyAdmin due to the illegal mix of collations error BUT when I query the secondary view from my code it works... so for now I can move on with my project. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: You can set the session connection collation from your code. Phpmyadmin does the same, this is why you get an illegal mix of collation there and not in your code. You can probably ly configure phpmyadmin to use the connection collation you need.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'collation%';

Comment: I see `COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'` at the end -- does that apply to the `VIEW` or, more likely to `pa.product_id = p.ID`?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the input provided by @shadow in the comments above, I ended up with adding `COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'` to the `END as sku_class` line, so it's now reads as
`END COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci' as sku_class`.

This does the trick for me for the view I created. That said, I still run into an *illegal mix of collations* error message when using the view within a secondary view although it -weirdly enough- works without error message from my PHP PDO query...

I'll update this post when I figured out a way to remove the error message for the secondary view in phpMyAdmin as well.

Answer (score 0):

Ok - figured it out, I initially misread the error message so I was looking at the wrong section of my query.

This is actually the part that bugged me:

```
case
    when pd.sku_class not in ('s','t') then 'act'
```

The `pd.sku_class` apparently caused the collation issue, still no idea why because everything in the database and the tables are with utf8mb_unicode_ci. Only the server setting is with latin, so that must be the reason.

Anyway, changing `pd.sku_class not in ('s','t')` into `not find_in_set( cast( pd.sku_class as char ), 's,t' )` did the trick!

```
case
    when not find_in_set( cast( pd.sku_class as char ), 's,t' ) then 'act'
```

So it is now all working for me. Hopefully this helps someone else in the future too :)